# Intgrating acceleo with jboss errai and gwt

Tags: gwt, jboss, emf, acceleo, errai

I have to create a project in jboss errai with GWT but I want to generate must of my model code using acceleo using eclipse modeling framework .ecore model. I have done this things.

1. created maven project using command

mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.jboss.errai.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=cdi-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=2.2.0.Final

1. Imported project to eclipse as existing maven project.
2. Goes to Acceleo->Convert Project to  Acceleo Generator Project but getting  nothing.
3. Then I goes to Acceleo->Convert to Acceleo MTL Projects and created a new acceleo project and generated model to my previous project using .ecore model but getting error in model class as I am getting EString at String
   and other also as E-datatype ,plz suggest solution how can I use acceleo feature into my jboss errai maven project.

my template file is as :

```
[comment encoding = UTF-8 /]
[module main('http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore')  ]



[template public generateElement(anEClass : EClass)]
[comment @main /]
[file (anEClass.name.concat('.java'), false, 'UTF-8')]
    public class [anEClass.name.toUpperFirst()/]{
[ for (p:EAttribute|anEClass.eAttributes) separator('\n')]
private [p.eAttributeType.name/] [p.name/];
[/for]

[ for (p:EAttribute|anEClass.eAttributes)  separator('\n')]
public  [p.eAttributeType.name/]  get[p.name.toUpperFirst()/]()
{

    return this.[p.name/];


}
[/for]

[ for (p:EAttribute|anEClass.eAttributes) separator('\n')]
public  void set[p.name.toUpperFirst()/]([p.eAttributeType.name/] [p.name/])
{
 this.[p.name/]=[p.name/];
}
[/for]


[protected ('protected')]

[/protected]

}



[/file]
[/template]
```

The one of model generated from .ecore model is as

```
public class UserRegistration {
    private EString strFirstName;
    private EString strSurName;
    private EString strOccupation;
    private EString strQualificaion;
    private EString strFotherName;
    private EString strMotherName;
    private EEList chMaritalStatus;
    private EDouble dblAnnualIncome;
    private EDate dtDOB;
    private EString strAbout;
    private EJavaClass objAcceleo;

    public EString getStrFirstName() {
        return this.strFirstName;
    }

    public EString getStrSurName() {
        return this.strSurName;
    }

    public EString getStrOccupation() {
        return this.strOccupation;
    }

    public EString getStrQualificaion() {
        return this.strQualificaion;
    }

    public EString getStrFotherName() {
        return this.strFotherName;
    }

    public EString getStrMotherName() {
        return this.strMotherName;
    }

    public EEList getChMaritalStatus() {
        return this.chMaritalStatus;
    }

    public EDouble getDblAnnualIncome() {
        return this.dblAnnualIncome;
    }

    public EDate getDtDOB() {
        return this.dtDOB;
    }

    public EString getStrAbout() {
        return this.strAbout;
    }

    public EJavaClass getObjAcceleo() {
        return this.objAcceleo;
    }

    public void setStrFirstName(EString strFirstName) {
        this.strFirstName = strFirstName;
    }

    public void setStrSurName(EString strSurName) {
        this.strSurName = strSurName;
    }

    public void setStrOccupation(EString strOccupation) {
        this.strOccupation = strOccupation;
    }

    public void setStrQualificaion(EString strQualificaion) {
        this.strQualificaion = strQualificaion;
    }

    public void setStrFotherName(EString strFotherName) {
        this.strFotherName = strFotherName;
    }

    public void setStrMotherName(EString strMotherName) {
        this.strMotherName = strMotherName;
    }

    public void setChMaritalStatus(EEList chMaritalStatus) {
        this.chMaritalStatus = chMaritalStatus;
    }

    public void setDblAnnualIncome(EDouble dblAnnualIncome) {
        this.dblAnnualIncome = dblAnnualIncome;
    }

    public void setDtDOB(EDate dtDOB) {
        this.dtDOB = dtDOB;
    }

    public void setStrAbout(EString strAbout) {
        this.strAbout = strAbout;
    }

    public void setObjAcceleo(EJavaClass objAcceleo) {
        this.objAcceleo = objAcceleo;
    }

    //Start of user code protected
    //End of user code
}
```

Here I am getting EString at place of String and other  primitive data type as E-Data type.

Plz suggest a solution How can I get java Data and other processor for the same

Answer (score 0):

Actually I got the core answer for my question I just modified in my mtl file

```
[comment encoding = UTF-8 /]
[module main('http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore')/]  
[template public generateElement(anEClass : EClass)]
[comment @main /]
[file (anEClass.name.concat('.java'), false, 'UTF-8')]
package com.garvityWeb.main.migrated.models;
@Portable
public class [anEClass.name.toUpperFirst()/]
{
[ for (p:EAttribute|anEClass.eAttributes) separator('\n')]
@Inject
@DataField
private [p.eAttributeType.instanceClassName/] [p.name/];
[/for]

[ for (p:EAttribute|anEClass.eAttributes)  separator('\n')]
public  [p.eAttributeType.instanceClassName/]  get[p.name.toUpperFirst()/]()
{
    return this.[p.name/];
}
[/for]
[ for (p:EAttribute|anEClass.eAttributes) separator('\n')]
public  void set[p.name.toUpperFirst()/]([p.eAttributeType.instanceClassName/] [p.name/])
{
 this.[p.name/]=[p.name/];
}
[/for]
}
[/file]
[/template]
```